# how to create SQL procedure which contains compile time errors?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I am writing a one time SQL procedure which will add an identity column to a table, then set the primary key of the table to that new identity column.  But I cannot compile the SQL procedure because the CREATE PROCEDURE statement returns a compile error.

How to tell SQL to create the procedure despite the compile error?

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE TESTSQL(                                
 )                                                                  
LANGUAGE    SQL                                                     
SPECIFIC        ORDHEADP5T                                          
SET OPTION   DATFMT    = *ISO, DLYPRP = *YES, DBGVIEW = *SOURCE,    
             USRPRF    = *OWNER, DYNUSRPRF = *OWNER, COMMIT = *CHG  
BEGIN                                                               
                                                                    
alter table   ordheader                                             
add column   ordidnum int generated always as identity ;            
                                                                    
alter table     ordheader                                           
add constraint  pk_ordheader primary key ( ordidnum ) ;             
                                                                    
end
```

```
SQL0205  30      14  Position 44 Column ORDIDNUM not in table ORDHEADER
```

Comment: Your code is using static-SQL which means that all objects (and columns) must PRE-EXIST at compilation time.  So, for your scenario , consider using dynamic-SQL instead of static-SQL ( using statements like  prepare, execute, or execute immediate etc)..  Learn about dynamic-SQL in any standard textbook, and google for examples for your i-series platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this one if you reduce it to one alter table like :

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE TESTSQL()                                                                  
LANGUAGE    SQL                                                     
SPECIFIC        ORDHEADP5T                                          
SET OPTION   DATFMT    = *ISO, DLYPRP = *YES, DBGVIEW = *SOURCE,    
             USRPRF    = *OWNER, DYNUSRPRF = *OWNER, COMMIT = *CHG  
BEGIN                                                               
alter table   ordheader                                             
    add column   ordidnum int generated always as identity          
    add constraint  pk_ordheader primary key ( ordidnum ) ;             
end
```